# Converting .ipynb python file to .py through windows powershell not working

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter-notebook

I have a `.ipynb` file with name *testingJupyter.ipynb* and I want to convert it to `.py` format file using *Windows Powershell*.

**I have run the following commands**

```
    pip install ipython
    pip install nbconvert
```

Then I go to the path where my *testingJupyter.ipynb* file is located and run the following command

`jupyter nbconvert --to script testingJupyter.ipynb`

But I get the **error**:

```
jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
```

And I have also tried running the following command

`ipython nbconvert --to script testingJupyter.ipynb`

Even then I get the **error** :

```
"ipython : The term 'ipython' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use fully qualified paths to jupyter and ipython, or add their directories to your path.

Comment: @vonPryz Thanks a lot for your reply. Can you please give me an example of fully qualified path. I do not know its meaning. I tried to google it but did not understand how to give the fully qualified path or how to add the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR, assuming Python's installed in Program Files\Python directory:

```
& "c:\program files\python\ipython" nbconvert ... whatever parameters
```

The error is caused because Powershell doesn't know where the executables (a fancier name for a program) are.

A bit background is in order. In Windows (and other operating systems too), there is an environmental variable called as `PATH`. When a user is trying to run an executable, the operating system needs to know where the program actually is located on the disk. This is because it is perfectly legal to have different programs with same names. For example, you could have two Python installations. 2.7 for legacy work and 3.9 for new development. If you just tell the OS to run Python, which one would it start? There is no way to know, and the OS does't really want to guess.

The solution is either to tell the OS explicitly the right location, or telling it where to look and in which order to look.

The explicit version uses fully qualified (also called as absolute) path. It contains drive letter (in Windows) and directory name. Like so

```
c:\program files\python2.7\python.exe
c:\program files\python3.9\python.exe
```

Since there are spaces in the path name, one needs to type it into shell so that the shell doesn't get confused. Usually, when a shell sees a space, it assumes that all the stuff to the left was command and stuff after space are going to be parameters to the command. Since `program files` is part of the program's location, that's a wrong guess. So, to run said game.exe, use the call operator and put the full path in quotes like so,

```
& "c:\program files\python2.7\python.exe"
```

For `command.com` shell, the ampersand is not used. Using double quotes is sufficient.

Another a way is to include Python's directory in the default search path. Then when you run `python`, the OS will look all the directories specified in the path, and stop looking when it finds the exe.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. I understood everything here but I am not able to add jupyter to my powershell PATH. When I tried to run this command from anaconda, it run fine (I assume this is because jupyter is in my anaconda environment). Can you please tell how I can add jupter to my powershell path also so that I can run this command from powerhsell too